# Simple AngularJS - controller values not binding

Tags: angularjs, controller

I'm completely new to front end development so please excuse the noob question, but can someone help me figure out what is wrong with this very simple AngularJS example? The output is just "{{tag.name}} {{tag.snippet}}".
I must be doing something very basic wrong, but from all the examples I have read online I can't figure out what it is... I am specifying ng-app, ng-controller and importing the js file... what else is there??

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head ng-app="reportingApp">
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>   
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="TagListController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tag in tags">
             {{tag.name}} {{tag.snippet}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following controllers.js file:

```
var reportingApp = angular.module('reportingApp', []);

reportingApp.controller('TagListController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.tags = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. put your `controllers.js` file **after** your `angular.js` script file.
2. try placing your `ng-app` attribute on the `html` element or some 
   element other than the `head`. The `head` tag gets closed before even
   reaching the `body` tag.

example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/JPWfLLz7T9BHemrJuH3z?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, it was the order! The ng-app in the head was a copy and paste error on my part, but it did not work with simply putting that in the html element. The order did it though... Such a simple thing, but if you don't know, you can waste so much time!

Comment: @dhalia - It is both issues, not just the order. If you play with the plnkr demo, and put the `ng-app` attribute on the head, you can see the page no longer works. `ng-app` will not make your controller work if you place your `ng-app` on a sibling element of the controller's element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got the ng-app up in the HEAD and not down in the body where you want it.

```
 <body ng-app="reportingApp" ng-controller="TagListController">
```

You don't need or want the ng-app in the head tag.